# Is there a way to run existing ASP.NET Web API in Azure Kubernetes Service?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-aks

I have an existing ASP.NET Web API, and I would like to deploy it to Azure Kubernetes Service. So far, I have only found tutorials showing how to deploy ASP.NET **Core** Web API Apps. Can anyone guide me towards the tutorial for pure ASP.NET Web API AKS deployment and not the Core one?

Answer (score 1):

I would say the first step is to containerize your app. There's a good source of information about it in here: https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopModernizing/wiki/02.-How-to-containerize-the-.NET-Framework-web-apps-with-Windows-Containers-and-Docker

After that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/windows-container-cli